# css - Video is only resizing on width change not on window height changes

Tags: css, reactjs, iframe

When changing the window height my iframe is not getting smaller. I can't figure out what the problem is. As it is resizing on width change.

The only thing I can think off is to listen to window resize event but it feels a bit strange if I need to do this.

See [example link](https://react-ts-umyrbd.stackblitz.io) and to edit see: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-umyrbd)

Comment: Can you share you code?

Comment: I made a example just follow this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-umyrbd

Answer (score 0):

**The height attribute specifies the height of a cell.**

```html
  <video width="100%" height="100%" controls>
        <source src="YourVideoPath.mkv" type="video/mp4">
        

      </video>
```